# simple for loop Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this little code here.

```
var fleet = [];
var number

var Taxi = function(color, badgeNumber) {
    this.color = "Yellow";
    this.badgeNumber = number;
}
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    fleet[i] = new Taxi;
    number = i;
}
for(var i = 0; i < fleet.length; i++) {
    print("Taxi with badge number " + fleet[i].badgeNumber + " is " + fleet[i].color);
}
```

which returns this:

```
Taxi with badge number 4 is Yellow
Taxi with badge number 0 is Yellow
Taxi with badge number 1 is Yellow
Taxi with badge number 2 is Yellow
Taxi with badge number 3 is Yellow
```

I aim to do that the number would print out in ascending order. Obviously it should start with 0. I like to keep it as simple as possible, so the question would be I guess why is not printing it in the right order?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign number before assigning to the array. When you assign number after setting the fleet, you're taking the number that is not current and assigning it to badge number. You won't need to sort the array once you do this.

```
for (var i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
    number = i;
    fleet[i] = new Taxi;
}
```

Comment: @user4274735 No Worries

Answer (score 1):

Before printing in a for loop, sort the array using below code:

```
fleet.sort(function(a,b){return a.badgeNumber - b.badgeNumber})
```

Comment: You are most welcome. If you think answer helped, please close this question by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make another for loop.  Just edit the loop you have to this and should fix the issue.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    fleet[i] = new Taxi;
    number = i;
    print("Taxi with badge number " + fleet[i].badgeNumber + " is " + fleet[i].color);
}
```

This will always print in order.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var fleet = [];
 var number;

  var Taxi = function(color,badgeNumber)
  {
   this.color="Yellow";
   this.badgeNumber=number;
   }
  for (var i=0; i < 5; i++)
   {
  number = i;     
  fleet[i] = new Taxi;

   }
 for(var i = 0; i< fleet.length; i++)
  {
 alert("Taxi with badge number " + fleet[i].badgeNumber + " is " + fleet[i].color);
  }
</script>   
 </head>

  </html>
```